# How to find local imports in a python file?(using modulegraph)

Tags: python, import, module, local

Is there a way to get a list of only local modules(scripts) imported by a python script?

I mean that I have 2 files. The scanned, and the scanner.And I need to determine which local modules the scanned one uses(maybe using modulegraph/modulefinder) but I couldnt find an answer myself.

**Edit:** I actually need to do this without importing the scanned module in the scanner one, so like a file scanning way.

Answer (score 0):

I've approached it by filtering all objects in the other module to check whether they are of type module.
This isn't super efficient, but I don't think it would need to be.

```
import foo # your module

import types
print dict((k, v) for (k, v) in foo.__dict__.iteritems() if type(v)==types.ModuleType)
```

Comment: Yeah, it doesnt need to be efficient its just run one for each file and I wont be proccesing more than 20 files at once. But I need it to work without importing the target module. Do you know any way where you just have a path to the target file and thats it?

Answer (score 0):

Since python is a lot more dynamic that say, C/Java, it is problematic if you can not import/run the scanned modules. Consider this type of code:

```
re = __import__('re')
mymodule = __import__(raw_input()) # even worse for you
```

Depending on how well you know your modules that you scan, doing text searching might or might not be fine.

Comment: I will probably just ignore the dynamic imports,(Im actually coding a Python obsufcator which can work with multiple source files and classes) and its ok for it to ignore dynamic imports. However , I will look into that later. Right now I found that `bbfreeze` uses `modulegraph` to do exactly what I need, so Im gonna use that approach. Thanks!

Comment: Ok figured it out with modulegraph, will post an answer when I have it nicely coded.